# How to clone IncomingMessage Object in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, request, formidable

I want to copy the Incoming Message Object in Node js.

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import * as formidable from 'formidable'

export const returnFiles = (req: Request) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = formidable({ multiples: true })
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }

      return resolve({
        files,
        fields,
      })
    })
  })
}

export const FileHandler = () => {
  return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const data = await returnFiles(req)
    console.log(data)
    return next()
  }
}
```

Basically when I want to be on safe side that if someone tries to do something in `returnFiles` it will not crash the whole server.

I have tried many things like

```
Object.assign
```

Spread Operator `...req`

But they are not working.

if someone know, Why It is not possible because this is a object altogether?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to work around the _actual_ problem. FWIW, [`IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage) is a stream, you can't "clone" it as such.

Comment: Yes, i want to work around, I have been using Node js from very long time i never had this question. can you explain me why this is the problem.

Comment: How do you intend to use the cloned object? What does "if someone tries to do something" mean?

Comment: Oh i red about it here solved my confusion

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/is_not_iterable